# Will objects on heap be replicated on stack on function call?

Tags: java, recursion, space-complexity

In Java, would an on-heap object be replicated on stack when a method is called? Consider this code -

```
static void mirror(Node p){
    if (p!=null) {
        Node temp = null;
        temp = p.left;
        p.left = p.right;
        p.right = temp;

        mirror(p.left);
        mirror(p.right);
    }
}
```

Would the space complexity be -

1. O(n) because the Node object p is pushed/replicated on stack on every recursive call
2. O(1) because the Node object is already in memory and p is just a reference to it
3. O(n) because the reference p is being pushed on stack on method calls

Edit: where n is the depth of the tree

Comment: 2. Objects are not implicitly copied in Java.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your comments.

Comment: if (p == null) { return; }  :-p   also temp= null is redundant as you init it straight after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of them.

Objects are *not* copied when passing their references to parameters of a method invocation, but references itself still occupy stack space, so the space-complexity is `O(n)` assuming that `n` refers to the depth of your binary tree.

The `O(…)` notation ignores constant scale factors, therefore `O(n)` only implies that there is an amount of stack space required for every recursion which is even true if you don’t pass any parameter to the invoked method. It does not tell how much space is required.

---

Edit: now that you have edited your question adding point 3, it’s point 3, but not exactly because, as said, there is stack space required even if you don’t push a reference on the stack.

---

Also keep in mind that you have to make clear what `n` refers to. If `n` is the total number of `Node`s of your tree, it’s rather `O(log(n))` if the tree is balanced. But if `n` is the maximum depth of your tree which matches the maximal recursion depth, then it’s `O(n)`.

Comment: Let's say a method that does nothing besides calling itself and exiting on some condition. Would the same hold true in this case when there are no method level variables at all?

Comment: In principle, yes, as normally information about the caller will be pushed on the stack to remember where to continue operation when returning. Usually the JVM will support debuggable stack traces as well. However, there are certain optimizations which might transform the code to a non-recursive operation at runtime so this statement is not the absolute truth. But this is highly JVM-implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The object p will not be copied on the heap, but for each recursion a reference to p will be put in the stack.